# Does the value attribute in input type = "number" accept php

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to set an attribute to the result of a PHP expression, like so

```
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->user_id; ?>" name="user_id" min="0" />
```

However NetBeans is showing me the following error

> Bad value "   " for attribute "value" on element "input": Expected a minus sign, a dot or a digit but saw " " instead.
>
> Syntax of floating point number:
>
> A floating point number consists of one of more digits ('0'–'9'), optionally with a single point ('.') somewhere (either before these numbers, in between two numbers, or after the numbers), all optionally prefixed with a hyphen ('-'). Examples: '42', '.42', '-4.2'
>
> From line 15, column 17; to line 15, column 74 (Rule Category: Attributes)

This is the full code for the form:

```
<form action="huffaz.php" method="post" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Your Personal Details <?php echo $loggedInUser->username; ?>
        </legend>
        <label>User ID</label>
        <input type="number" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->user_id; ?>" name="user_id" min="0" />
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" required />
        <label>Surname:</label>
        <input type="text" name="surname" required />
        <label>Age at 1st Ramadhan:</label>
        <input type="number" name="age" min="15" value="15" required />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Your Contact Details
        </legend>
        <label>Town/City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" required/>
        <label>County/State:</label>
        <input type="text" name="state" required/>
        <label>Country:</label>
        <input type="text" name="country" required/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Your Qualifications
        </legend>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you tested it first?!

Comment: Using the latest version of netbeans?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't rely on `type="number"` right now.. there should be some additional JS and definitely server-side validation.

Comment: Bad value "   " for attribute "value" on element "input": Expected a minus sign, a dot or a digit but saw " " instead.
Syntax of floating point number:
A floating point number consists of one of more digits ('0'–'9'), optionally with a single point ('.') somewhere (either before these numbers, in between two numbers, or after the numbers), all optionally prefixed with a hyphen ('-'). Examples: '42', '.42', '-4.2'

From line 15, column 17; to line 15, column 73
(Rule Category: Attributes)

Comment: That is an HTML5 input type only. FYI.

Comment: But doesnt netbeans support html5

Comment: Are you sure you are editing a PHP file? This error doesn't come up in my NetBeans.

Comment: BTW: its the latest version 7.3.1

Comment: It does support HTML5 the error is telling it thinks there is a problem with the value based on the fact that it is looking for a number.

Comment: Yes, its a .php file.

Comment: I just tested in NetBeans and it doesn't flag it as an error either.

Comment: Yes, thats what I understood that its looking for a number, but php will echo a number.

Comment: Your netbeans config may not be set properly to handle html5. perhaps it's still configured for html4 only.

Comment: <fieldset>
<legend>
Your Personal Details <?php echo $loggedInUser->username; ?>
</legend>
<label>User ID</label>
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $loggedInUser->user_id; ?>" name="user_id" min="0" />
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" required />
                <label>Surname:</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" required />
                <label>Age at 1st Ramadhan:</label>
                <input type="number" name="age" min="15" value="15" required />
            </fieldset>

Comment: Thats my piece of code. Doctype is set to html5

Comment: You should put code in your question not in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know that. I am a newcomer to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this error being shown when you run the application, or just in the Netbeans IDE?

I suspect what is happening is that Netbeans is attempting to make sure that your HTML is valid, and so its checking that the value of your input field is actually a number, but its just running in the IDE and so `$loggedInUser->user_id` doesn't have any value and so its giving this validation error - if this is the case then it might well work at runtime.

If you see this error at runtime then the problem is probably that `$loggedInUser->user_id` is empty when it should in fact be a number - you need to look at what should be populating that user id and figure out why its not working as you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, it is only in Netbeans IDE that I am getting this error. Other than that it is working fine when I run the code.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this specific warning?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration option to turn off / tune this warning:

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints -> HTML Validator -> Attributes